# Format decimal value to currency with optional precision

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have c# project. I use `ToString("N", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`  for format double value and the result is like **1.254.812,45** .There is no problem. But when I have no precision I don't want to display **1.254.812,00**. I want to display only **1.254.812** .  How can I do it?

Comment: Split this into two problems and you can find your answer. First, [c# check if decimal is a whole number](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+check+if+decimal+is+a+whole+number), then [c# ToString double without decimals](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+ToString+double+without+decimals)

Comment: What about a value like `1200.1` should that output "1.200,1" or "1.200,10"?

Comment: this type is not problem for me. I display it like 1.200,10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a direct solution, but the `Convert()` method I developed provides a solution.

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static string Convert(string value)
    {
        if(value.Split('.')[1].Equals("00"))
            return value.Split('.')[0];
        return value;
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] inputs = {1254812.00, 1254812.45};
        string[] results = {inputs[0].ToString("N", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), inputs[1].ToString("N", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)};
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", Convert(results[0]), Convert(results[1]));
    }
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
1,254,812    1,254,812.45
```

Comment: The main issue with this code is that it will only work if you format the number with a culture that uses period for the decimal separator (which based on the OPs question is not the case for them)

Comment: I just use it to format the number for display to user after ajax post. this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the [custom format specifier `#`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier)**, which only returns decimal digits if they exist in the number, both before the decimal point and after.

For example, for `de-DE` culture:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(1254812.45.ToString("#,###.###", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")));
Console.WriteLine(1254812.0.ToString("#,###.###", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")));
```

Output

```
1.254.812,45
1.254.812
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V8Uk3m)

Comment: the main issue with this is that if the number is "1200.1" then it outputs "1.200,1" and I bet the OP would actually want "1.200,10"